# UIImagepickercontroller: is it possible to change the sort order of the images in camera roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

Basically the app im working on would be a lot less of a pain if users didn't have to scroll to the very bottom of their camera roll to get their most recent photos, I want the most recent at the top, wouldn't this make sense anyway? Not sure why apple designed it this way, or if im just not realizing something.

Thanks

nick

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind adding an extra step of selecting the camera roll from an album list you can try changing your sourceType from SavedPhotoAlbums to PhotoLibrary:

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

After selecting the desired album, the next photo selection view will show the most recent images at the bottom.

Comment: thank you for this! the fact that it starts from the latest does not seem to be documented anywhere, so you saved me a bunch of time :)

Comment: thanks, I never paid attention to this. Was this working before? I remember I didn't find this as 1/2 yeas ago. That time, the solution is to use AssetLibrary. Luckily, I googled again this time, and found your tip. Appreciate/

Comment: This is the correct way to handle the issue. Great job reading the docs haha

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to customize UIImagePickerController in this way, but as of iOS 4.0, you can basically build your own image picker in any way you like using the [AssetsLibrary framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730).

Answer (score 0):

You can get images, using ALAsset in an arry, and then can sort them as you want and use in table view or collectionview to build your own custom album