# How do I make ImagePicker start at the bottom to show most recent images first?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

When the user selects "Choose existing," the view loads at the top and displays the oldest pictures first. However, I would like it to load at the bottom to show the most recently taken images. I know this is possible because it is the default behavior in Apple's iMessage and Facebook apps.

Answer (score 1):

look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3947261/641062.

Look at this for creating custom imagepicker http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/