# iPhone how to pick a latest taken image with default UIImagePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sorting, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an option to display a UIImagePicker and select an image from the user's camera roll within my app. THe issue that I'm running in is that the **photos are sorted with the oldest on top**. This makes it easy to pick images that have been taken months ago. I want the user to quickly select images that were taken a few minutes ago without having to scroll to the end of the list (bottom of the list).

**Is there  away to ask the default UIImagePicker to sort its results and display latest ones or at least scroll to the end of the list after being presented?**

```
- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                                   usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                                   UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {

    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)   
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;


    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
    // movie capture, if both are available:
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947157/uiimagepickercontroller-is-it-possible-to-change-the-sort-order-of-the-images-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in this [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947157/uiimagepickercontroller-is-it-possible-to-change-the-sort-order-of-the-images-i)

the solution involves adding an extra step before selecting an image with the line:

```
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

This displays the list of available photo libraries and scrolls to the bottom of the selected one.