# iOS didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo camera roll order newest Images at top

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

A quick question how do you reverse the order that the camera roll is shown i.e newest images at the top rather than having to scroll all the way to the bottom to get newest image? Alas Facebook image picker?

Comment: They are doing an entirely custom view for this, there is no way to do it with the standard `UIImagePickerController`

Comment: @Dan Fairazi I didnt think it was poss but thought Id ask. I may try just auto scrolling the view to the bottom as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in the sense that its just one extra step to select album then images are presented latest first UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary rather than UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution to this

-Using AssetsLibrary frmaework you can have the view completely customised as per your requirement.

Reference : 
[UIImagepickercontroller: is it possible to change the sort order of the images in camera roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947157/uiimagepickercontroller-is-it-possible-to-change-the-sort-order-of-the-images-][1]i)