# Why does UIImagePickerController NOT sort most recent photos first when using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary?

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

**EDIT: After updating to iOS 7.0.3 the problem is gone**

I would like the UIImagePickerController to display photos in a way that the user can access most recent photos first (I am working with iOS7).

I am following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10023924/2007515 , so my function looks like:

```
- (IBAction)action_album:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But the result is not what I want:

1. the "Photos" overview is presented (good)
2. if I pick "Camera Roll" the oldest photos are displayed on top and I have to scroll all the way down to get the most recent ones (not good)

Could someone tell me what I'm missing here? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and it's making me crazy. I thought it was just my app because every other photo app displays correctly, but not mine. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out. This seems to be some kind of Apple bug. If your statusbar is hidden when using the UIImagePickerController, the image picker does not automatically scroll to the bottom (newest) and stays at the top (oldest). If I let the status bar show when using the image picker, it auto scrolls to the bottom like it should. Thanks a lot, Apple.

Comment: you're right, if I un-hide the status bar, everything works as it should - but unfortunately I need it to stay hidden :(